# How to return object from list in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have retrieved a static table from a database in a list.
If someone calls the constructor of that class with an ID, the constructor finds the object in the list and copies all values.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MyClass(int instanzId)
    {
        MyClass myClass = CachedList().Find(T => T.Id == instanzId);
        Id = myClass.Id;
        Text = myClass.Text;
    }
}
```

This will always create a new instance of that object.
Is it possible to return the object from the list directly?
Like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MyClass(int instanzId)
    {
        this = CachedList().Find(T => T.Id == instanzId);
    }
}
```

I know it's easy in a static method, but how can that be done in the constructor?

Comment: You can't return any values from a constructor, and you can't assign values to 'this'.

Comment: what is your end goal?

Comment: *This will always create a new instance of that object.* - and you are expecting what, when calling `new MyClass()`?

Comment: @DanielA.White: At least, not in a *class* constructor. In a *struct* constructor you can assign to this...

Comment: I would write whatever crap I could think of to have @JonSkeet correct me. :)

Comment: In some languages, (i.e. JavaScript) it is possible to *replace* the object being constructed with an object returned from constructor but this is not the case in C#. (Note this is a waste of resources since object is created and discarded and some find this behavior counter-intuitive in general).

Comment: Background is: 
The called of the constructor must not know if this class is cached or not. If it's not cached a new instance with data from the db is created.

Comment: @MichaelK, you previously said (implied) that all the values were cached. How does using a factory method reveal whether it's cached?

Comment: If you are going to go to the trouble of  caching then put it in Dictionary.  List find might not be faster than a database call.  And why can't you use a method call?  New is going to give you a new object so changes will not reference back to the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well no, not via constructor. You can do it via a method. For example a factory:

```
public MyClass FindOrCreate(int instanceId)
{
    MyClass obj = CachedList().Find(T => T.Id == instanzId);
    //create obj when it does not exist

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelK, it's your only option if you don't want to create a new instance.

Comment: Unfortunately. 
I thought there was a better way than copying the properties.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap cache into just another lightweight class:

```
  public class MyWrapClass {
    private MyClass m_Cache;

    public MyWrapClass() {
      m_Cache = CachedList().Find(T => T.Id == instanzId);
      ...
    }
    ...

    // implicit cast to MyClass if you want it 
    public static implicit operator MyClass(MyWrapClass value) {
      if (null == value)
        return null;
      else
        return value.m_Cache;
    }
  }

  ...
  // Or MyWrapClass test = new MyWrapClass();
  MyClass test = new MyWrapClass();
```

Comment: except the clear wtf? when reading `MyClass test = new MyWrapClass();` months later I really like the cleverness of this attempt.